# Firefox fails on CORS resource, while Chrome and Safari work

Tags: firefox, cors, couchdb, axios

I have a seemingly correct resource backed by a CouchDB installation. Requests are made using JS Axios. Both Chrome and Safari work, Firefox 65.0 fails however with

```
CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'http://localhost:8080, *'
```

The server (CouchDB) does, in fact, not deliver

```
 'http://localhost:8080, *' as Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

but

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:8080
 Access-Control-Expose-Headers content-type, cache-control, a…e-newrev, x-couchdb-body-time
```

due to its configuration CORS accept requests from all domains ('*').

This, as mentioned, perfectly works for the other browsers. But fails for Firefox. I really don't seem to find the resason resp. a solution for this, and keep wondering where the additional '*' comes from that, Firefox wants to see.

Comment: This seems like the same problem described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592828/cross-origin-error-firefox-also-expects-asterisk-chrome-doesnt#comment96026238_54592828. Seems like it must be some bug in Firefox. (A bug introduced in Firefox 65 maybe?) Either that or maybe you’re have an extension installed that’s causing it. Have you tried testing with extensions off?

Comment: Another suggestion: Create a clean profile in in Firefox and see if you can reproduce the problem with that profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sideshowbarker thanks for the hint - indeed, the behaviour was due to an extension - namely this one https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cross-domain-cors/  after disabling this extension cors worked as expected!

Comment: I almost uninstalled Firefox because of this...

Answer (score 0):

## CORS issue only on firefox

If you have a CORS issue on Firefox but not on other browsers you might need to enable Enterprise Roots certificates

- go to the firefox page: `about:config`
- then search for enable `security.enterprise_roots.enabled`
- click on it a set it to `true`