# CORS request blocked in Firefox

Tags: firefox, cors, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a CORS get request to my server. My server is properly CORS enabled.

I am sending an additional header so preflighted option call is sent by browser.

This is working in Chrome but not in firefox. In firefox i can see the options call with 200 as return status code but the subsequent get call is not sent which is happening perfectly in Chrome

In firefox i see these messages in console

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://serverurl. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://tryit.w3schools.com, *’).[Learn More]

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://serverurl. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
```

I am making XMLHttpRequest call to trigger the call.

I am not able to figure why the call is failing in firefox

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue. It was because of the extension "allow cross origin". Disabling it worked.

Duplicate of [Firefox fails on CORS resource, while Chrome and Safari work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54618192/firefox-fails-on-cors-resource-while-chrome-and-safari-work)